# How to get coordinates in 2D starting from (0,0) with length and angle

Tags: javascript, math, svg, geometry, computational-geometry

I have the following coordinates

```
[-20, -20], [-20, 20], [-40, 0], [-40, 20], [-40, 40], [-20, 80], [20, 80], [40, 40], [80, 20], [80, -20].
```

My task is to get coordinates starting point from [0, 0].I can get the angles and the length from the above given coordinates. The angles should be between 0 to 360 positive.

Suppose I don't have the original coordinates now. I need to calculate the coordinates starting from 0,0 with angles and length.I need the current coordinate, previous and next coordinates.

Ex: if the current coordinates segment has a length of 5 then coordinates are (0,0) (0,5).The end point of the Predecessor is (0,0)and  the start point of the Successor is (0,5).

What could be the formula,
I need to calculate keeping in mind the quadrants and rotate it finally ??

To find the next and previous coordinates I use as in quadrant 1.
`x1=x+l * cos(angle), y1=y+l * sin(angle)`.

Do the above formulas change in my case w.r.t quadrants as below or they stand the same.

```
x1=x-l*cos(angle), y1=y-l*sin(angle) etc (change w.r.t quadrants).
```

Help me find out.

Actual Figure:

[image: Original Coordinates, this shape is flipped by y-axis]
Red is current, blue is predecessor, black is successor.

Comment: I think this belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Even here we have geometry and math community

Comment: What do mean by "normalized coordinates"? In some scenaries it means "*in {0, 1} range*". But it seems you are taking about cartesian-polar conversions.

Comment: I mean just that the coordinates must start from (0,0). Then from there the next point we take the length and it to y.I need to find the next coordinates and previous coordinates from this using x1=x+l * cos(angle), y1=y+l * sin(angle).I am confused above quadrants which they fall into to find the previous and next coordinate points. @Ripi2

Comment: Your question is not clear again. What stops you from subtracting the first cordinates from all others to provide starting form `0,0` ?

Comment: I updated , can you check. I need to find the coordinates starting from 0,0 with the length and angle of the segments. I use x1=x+l * cos(angle), y1=y+l * sin(angle) the formula to find the coordinates. Depending on angles or quadrants (i.e 90 to 180 is quadrant II), should I change the formula by +,- combinations @MBo

Comment: What to subtract , can you be more clear @MBo

Comment: `[-20, -20], [-20, 20], [-40, 0]  =>[0,0],[0,40],[-20,20]`

Comment: The last coordinate should be [-20,-20].Something like [-20, -20], [-20, 20], [-40, 0] =>[0,0],[0,40],[-20,-20]. I form two segments from these [0,0],[0,40],0.40][-20,-20], that is the current and next coordinates. What about previous ??

Comment: Can I render similar shape when it starts from (0,0). Or shall I rotate by any angle.

Comment: -40-(-20) =-20; 0-20=-20;

Comment: @MBo - Did you get the problem , any insights ??

Comment: No, I left the discussion

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179389/find-the-new-coordinates-using-a-starting-point-a-distance-and-an-angle this could be similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Not java, but python, since it was tagged 'computational geometry'. You can translate if needed

Not totally sure this is what you need, but you have a center and a series of points.  The angle (ie azimuth since it is from north) and the distance to those points can be calculated.

If it isn't what is needed, then you can pull out what you need from it.

```
a = np.array([[-20, -20], [-20, 20], [-40, 0], [-40, 20], [-40, 40], [-20, 80], [20, 80], [40, 40], [80, 20], [80, -20]])
pnt = np.array([0,0]

import numpy as np

def e_dist(a, b, metric='euclidean'):
    """Distance calculation for 1D, 2D and 3D points using einsum

    `a`, `b` : array like
        Inputs, list, tuple, array in 1, 2 or 3D form
    `metric` : string
        euclidean ('e', 'eu'...), sqeuclidean ('s', 'sq'...),
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    """
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.atleast_2d(b)
    a_dim = a.ndim
    b_dim = b.ndim
    if a_dim == 1:
        a = a.reshape(1, 1, a.shape[0])
    if a_dim >= 2:
        a = a.reshape(np.prod(a.shape[:-1]), 1, a.shape[-1])
    if b_dim > 2:
        b = b.reshape(np.prod(b.shape[:-1]), b.shape[-1])
    diff = a - b
    dist_arr = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', diff, diff)
    if metric[:1] == 'e':
        dist_arr = np.sqrt(dist_arr)
    dist_arr = np.squeeze(dist_arr)
    return dist_arr



def radial_sort(pnts, cent=None, as_azimuth=False):
    """Sort about the point cloud center or from a given point

    `pnts` : points
        An array of points (x,y) as array or list
    `cent` : coordinate
        list, tuple, array of the center's x,y coordinates
    >>> cent = [0, 0] or np.array([0, 0])

    Returns:
    -------
        The angles in the range -180, 180 x-axis oriented

    """
    pnts = np.asarray(pnts, dtype=np.float64)
    if cent is None:
        cent = _center(pnts, remove_dup=False)
    ba = pnts - cent
    ang_ab = np.arctan2(ba[:, 1], ba[:, 0])
    ang_ab = np.degrees(ang_ab)
    sort_order = np.argsort(ang_ab)
    if as_azimuth:
        ang_ab = np.where(ang_ab > 90, 450.0 - ang_ab, 90.0 - ang_ab)
    return ang_ab, sort_order
```

Now if you use 'a' and 'pnt' above, you get the following results.

```
    dist = e_dist(a, pnt)
    angles = radial_sort(a, pnt, True)[0]

    dist
    Out[36]: 
    array([28.284, 28.284, 40.   , 44.721, 56.569, 82.462, 82.462, 56.569, 82.462,
           82.462])

    angles
    Out[37]: 
    array([225.   , 315.   , 270.   , 296.565, 315.   , 345.964,  14.036,  45.   ,
            75.964, 104.036])
```

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179389/find-the-new-coordinates-using-a-starting-point-a-distance-and-an-angle this can be similar question